# Use Array in BPEL

Tags: arrays, apache, xsd, bpel

I would like to create an array using XSD and use the same in my BPEL(Apache ODE) and insert values into the same.

XSD:

```
<complexType name="datesOfActivation">
<sequence>
    <element name="dates" type="date" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">    </element>
</sequence>
</complexType>
    <element name="TaskDates" type="tns:datesOfActivation">
</element>
```

Here is how I am trying to insert values in it (BPEL):

```
<bpel:copy>
<bpel:from>$date</bpel:from>
<bpel:to>$TaskDates/tns:dates[$counter]/text()</bpel:to>
</bpel:copy>
```

Counter is a variable which starts with 1. date is a simple variable whose value I want to pass in the array. When I execute it I get only a single value in array in the end. (I increase the counter value)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using **while** instruction bellow.

```
<while condition="bpws:getVariableData('var1', 'TestPart') &lt; 10">
    <assign>
       <copy>
         <from expression="bpws:getVariableData('var1', 'TestPart') + 1"/>
         <to variable="var1" part="TestPart"/>
      </copy>
    </assign>
   </while>
```